# Dimension Mismatch using melt() in reshape2

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape, reshape2, melt

I am trying to melt a data frame from 'wide' format to 'long' format in R, using the function 'melt' in the package 'reshape2'. However, I am encountering an issue with dimensions when trying to view the output data frame which I am having trouble deciphering. Here is an example:

```
# load reshape2 package
require(reshape2)

# sample data frame generated using dput
df <- structure(list(year = c(2001, 2002, 2003, 2004), 
                     aet = structure(c(493.1, 407.1, 476.7, 501.6), .Dim = 4L), 
                     drainage = structure(c(5.4, 5.4, 5.4, 5.4), .Dim = 4L), 
                     srunoff = structure(c(25.6, 24.3, 56.0, 50.3), .Dim = 4L)),
                .Names = c("year", "aet", "drainage", "srunoff"), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")

# if i melt without specifying id.vars, it provides a warning but works works fine
df.melt <- melt(df)

# check output
head(df.melt)

# view output
View(df.melt)
# this works fine, and the data frame is visible in RStudio

# now, melt while supplying year as an id variable
df.melt.id <- melt(df, id.vars="year")

# check output
head(df.melt.id)
# the first 6 lines of output print to the console menu, as normal

# view output
View(df.melt.id)
```

However, when I try to view the df.melt.id data frame, I get the following error:

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  dims [product 4] do not match the length of object [12]
```

4 corresponds to the original length of the data frame, and 12 is how long it should be. If I check the dimensions using `dim(df.melt.id)`, it returns the appropriate size: `[1] 12  3`

Any ideas on what's going on here? I have tried re-installing reshape2 and that did not help...

Comment: If you look at `str(df.melt.id)`, somehow the `value` column became an array. If you coerce it to numeric, it's fine, but the behavior seems pretty buggy.

Comment: It's a `reshape2` thing; `reshape::melt.data.frame` works fine.

Comment: Strange! Yes, using `reshape` works fine on both this sample and my original, larger data frame. Thanks for the quick help.

Comment: You should also [file a bug report](https://github.com/hadley/reshape/issues).

Comment: And try my answer :P

Comment: Bug report filed, answer tried!

Comment: The problem is that your original columns in the `data.frame` are arrays (they have a length one `dim` attribute) and those are not properly handled by `reshape2`. I've submitted a PR to fix that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works with `reshape2` when you do this:

```
df.melt.id <- as.data.frame.array(melt(df, id="year"))
```